# Zoom To Multiple Markers bounds not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am tying to add some Markers to the map, which is working fine, but I can't set the map to zoom to the bounds(extend) of all the markers. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['Tacloban', 11.247524,125.00463],
    ['Guiuan', 11.034212,125.731659],
    ['Ormoc', 11.026798,124.600754],
    ['Cebu', 10.31019,123.881836],
    ['Roxas', 11.59036,122.763977]

];
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('alloffice'), 'click', function() {
  map.setCenter(latlngOfficeAall);
  map.setZoom(8);
// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2], markers[i][3], markers[i][4], markers[i][5]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });
        }

  });
```

Comment: Where do you call [map.fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the map to center and zoom to fit the bounds with [map.fitBounds(bounds)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

```
// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['Tacloban', 11.247524,125.00463],
    ['Guiuan', 11.034212,125.731659],
    ['Ormoc', 11.026798,124.600754],
    ['Cebu', 10.31019,123.881836],
    ['Roxas', 11.59036,122.763977]

];

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('alloffice'), 'click', function() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
  for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2], markers[i][3], markers[i][4], markers[i][5]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_zoom2markers.html)

Comment: Hi geocodezip, I updated my code as you commented but it is still not zooming to the boundries of all markers. I thought I should remove the map.setCenter(latlngOfficeAall); and map.setZoom(8); lines from code but the map still not zooming to the extends of the Markers!

Comment: Did you fix the javascript errors and/or define all the required external variables? When I fix those it works for me (it wasn't tested originally as you don't provide the complete code).